# WatiN firing KeyDown event for the wrong keyCode

Tags: watin

If you look at the code in WatiN.Core.Element.cs you see the following:

```
private static NameValueCollection GetKeyCodeEventProperty(char character)
{
    return new NameValueCollection
               {
                   {"keyCode", ((int) character).ToString()},
                   {"charCode", ((int) character).ToString()}
               };
}
```

This is the code used to simulate the firing of client side events, for example when automating typing text into a text field. It seems to me that this code generates the wrong keyCodes.

Let's say that I type the letter "v" into a text box. (int)'v' returns 118. 118 is the keyCode for F7 not the keyCode for "v" which is 86.

Sure enough my application is detecting that F7 has been hit.

This just seems straightforwardly wrong. Am I missing something here - I can't believe that no one else would be seeing this issue if I weren't.

Thanks in advance,

Julian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a couple things are happening here.  Calling ((int)'[character]') is returning that character's decimal ASCII value.  Lowercase v is 118.  Uppercase V is 86.

```
Console.WriteLine("lowercase: " + ((int)'v').ToString());
Console.WriteLine("uppercase: " + ((int)'V').ToString()); 
Console.WriteLine("V in Keys Enumeration: " + ((int)System.Windows.Forms.Keys.V).ToString());
```

Looking through the call stack for *WatiN.Core.Element.KeyPress* it eventually gets down to call the following line of code in method *SetValueWhenOnKeyPress* in IEFireEventHandler.cs.

```
var newValue = _ieElement.GetAttributeValue("value") + ((char) int.Parse(addChar));
```

addChar is the keyCode item returned in *GetKeyCodeEventProperty*.   newValue is what is being used to set the Element's value, thus when you do something like myTextField.TypeText('v') a lowercase v is typed in your textbox.

*Note*: WatiN 2.1 code was reviewed for this.